# changing style of mui stepper

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, stepper

I would like to change the following code to meet my needs

I need to change the icon step from [image]

to this : [image]

I can not change the style and also add an intermediate step

I added `, '.Mui-active': { color: '#1C6FC9', },`
here is the link to the sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/horizontalnonlinearstepper-demo-material-ui-forked-9pqxxk

Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to this solution is to add a `padding` to the active icon, then drawing a round `border` around that.

```
".MuiSvgIcon-root.Mui-active": {
  padding: "3px",
  borderRadius: "50%",
  border: "1px solid #1976d2",
  marginY: "-4px"
}
```

`marginY: "-4px"` is there to balance the padding and border without breaking the spacing. `marginY` is equal to `marginTop` and `marginBottom`, thats why `-4 + -4 = -8` which equals to the added difference in padding plus border on both sides: `3 + 3 + 1 + 1 = 8`.

This is what the result looks like:

[image]

### Live Demo

[image: Edit HorizontalNonLinearStepper demo — Material UI (forked)]

Comment: @Abdelkader I gotchu ;)

Answer (score 0):

please add this style into your `css`. I hope this works

```
.css-1u4zpwo-MuiSvgIcon-root-MuiStepIcon-root.Mui-active {
    padding-right: 0;
    border: 2px solid #1C6FC9;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 6px;
}
```

Comment: @ Ahmad Faraz Hello , this is the result after adding the code but the circle is too small :-) I'm new in css can you tell me please how to change that